# Why the line bundle associated to the hyperplane is tautoloical line bundle

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $X = \Bbb{CP}^n$ , consider the hyperplane $H = \{z_0 = 0\}\subset\Bbb{CP}^n$ , we can define it as Weil divisor , then since the isomorphism between $$\text{Div}(X) \cong H^0(X,\mathcal{K}_X^*/\mathcal{O}_X^*)$$

we can associate this Divisor $H\in \text{Div}(X)$ as a set of $\{f_i\} \in H^0(X,\mathcal{K}_X^*/\mathcal{O}_X^*)$ ,this set of $\{f_i\}$ define a cocycle $\{\psi_{ij} = f_if^{-1}_j\}$ hence we have a canonical map from $$\text{Div} (X) \to \text{Pic}(X)$$via the cocycle above.

---

**Now I want to check that via this map $$\text{Div}(X) \to H^0(X,\mathcal{K}_X^*/\mathcal{O}_X^*)\to \text{Pic}(X)$$
we maps $H\in \text{Div}(X)$ to tautogical line bunle $\mathcal{O}(1)$**

the key is to find the cocycle if it has the form $$\psi_{ij} = z_i/z_j$$ then we can deduce it, however I don't know how to find such $\{f_i\}$?

---

My solution(if don't think about it too carefully this solution is sufficient):

Given the Weil divisor $H$ the corresponding Cartier divisor is:

$$\{(U_0,1),(U_1,z_0/z_1),...(U_n,z_0/z_n)\}
$$
where $U_i = \{(z_0:...:z_{n})\mid z_i \ne 0\}$
Therefore the cocycle is:

$$\psi_{ij} =f_if_j^{-1} = z_j/z_i$$

which is the same as the tautological line bundle $\mathcal{O}(1)$

Comment: Why do you keep answering your own questions in the comments? Answers go in the answer box (or if you're not sure that's an answer, you can add it in an [edit] to your post and ask if your solution is correct).

Comment: I think my answer is correct, I answer it as comment since I think this is not detailed enough (and... for some reason prevent others answer the question as comment again :) )

Comment: Don't do that. That's not what comments are for. Your addition should be either an [edit] to your question or an answer. If you're worried about people answering in the comments, you can ask them to make their comment an answer or use a flag.

Comment: thank you KReiser , edited it.

Comment: Here is how I think about this: The functions $f_i$ of the Cartier divisor should cut out the Weil divisor $H$ on $U_i$, i.e. $H \cap U_i = \{ x \in U_i : f_i(x) = 0\}$ (by $f_i(x) = 0$ I formally mean that $f_i$ is contained in the maximal ideal of $\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^n, x}$, but intuitively this means that $f_i$ vanishes at $x$). So your proposed functions $f_i = z_i / z_0$ are not correct. *What do you have to change that this works out?* I believe then it should also be clear what the $U_i$ have to be.

Comment: Thank you red_trumpet , correct it (a small typo)

Comment: Yes, now you still have to say what exactly the $U_i$ are.